# CouchDB Replicator

Tags: couchdb, document

I am trying to create a couchdb interface in which databases for multiple operating systems contain documents with identical keys but strings in different languages. I would like to use the Replicator function when I update the main file to notify me which documents do not have the update and which keys need to be created or updated.

Answer (score 1):

The `_rev` field is made by hashing the contents of the document, so it's not possible to have two different documents and use Couch'd replication.